# How to create MVC form from class with a List<T> property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am new to .NET MVC and am trying to figure out forms, I think I am on the right track but I am stuck trying to figure out how to create a form based off of a class that has an `ObservableCollection<>` of another class, for example:

```
public class Items
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

and Line Items is something like:

```
public class LineItem
{
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string QTY { get; set; }
}
```

From what I understand I should create an instance of `Items` in the controller and pass that to my view

`return View(new Items());`

Then on my view I use `HTML` helpers to create the form and when I submit the form, the model `Items` is sent back to the controller with filled out data. How do I go about having multiple `LineItems` in my view that bind to the `ObservableCollection<>` in my `Model` ? Let's say they need 2 `LineItems`, is there a programmatic way to show the inputs for `public ObservableCollection<LineItem> LineItems` multiple times, as an `ObservableCollection` is typically more than one instance of the class. I am using .NET MVC C# with Razor syntax.

Comment: To render controls for collections you use a `for` loop - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.LineItems.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LineItems[i].ItemNumber) }` or create a custom `EditorTemplate for typeof `LineItem`.

Comment: Here is one approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/26284038/84206 and here is a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/15375949/84206

Comment: @AaronLS these answers only seem to cover showing data that already exists in the class that is passed to the View, I am trying to create a new entry.

Comment: @user4612487 Creating a form for existing items and creating a form for new items is somewhat similar though.  You simply need to follow the same square brackets patterns for the HTML `name`, but instead of generating the HTML from Razor, you'd generate it dynamically with javascript when user clicks something like + button to add a new line form.

Comment: @user4612487, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) shows some options for dynamically adding new items to a collection.