# Using HTML.TextBoxFor to loop through items in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Probably a stupid question but I am new to MVC.

So far in my Razor I could say `@HTML.TextBoxFor(t => t.EmailAddress)`
but now I have a for-each:

```
foreach(var q in Model.Questions)
{
  // so here the t => t.EmailAddress  syntax is not working anymore.
}
```

I asked my question in the code sample above. So when I am inside a for-each loop how can I can use `@HTML.TextBox`  ? because now it doesn't get the lambda syntax anymore.

Comment: Use a `for` loop (a `foreach` will not work) - [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do not use `foreach`, because this will cause problems when you try to bind your inputs back to the model. Instead use a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Questions[i])
}
```

See also [Model Binding to a List MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4).

Comment: how about having two textboxes binded to two different properties.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use a `for` loop to accomplish this as you'll need the actual index of the element to bind to the `name` attribute, which is used to ensure that your values are properly posted to the server :

```
@for (var q = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); q++) { 
    // This will bind the proper index to the appropriate name attribute
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Questions[q])
}
```