# JQuery - Finding Model[n].FieldName and adding values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, .net

I am trying to the find, and add, the value of indexed fields in each row of a table.

```
 <tr>
   <td><input name="Model[0].Name" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[0].Sched" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[0].Comp" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[0].NoShow" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>                    
   <td><input name="Model[0].TotalHours" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input name="Model[1].Name" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[1].Sched" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[1].Comp" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
   <td><input name="Model[1].NoShow" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>                    
   <td><input name="Model[1].TotalHours" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
 </tr>
```

I would like to add Model[n].Sched + Model[n].Comp + Model[n].NoShow =  Model[n].TotalHours for each row.

I think there must be a simple solution to this, but I must be searching for a solution using in the incorrect keywords.

TIA!

Comment: Iterate over all rows, for each row, find all `input` elements and sum the values of the first 3?

Comment: There are other fields in the row.  I left them out because I thought they were irrelevant. So the first 3 wouldn't work.  There must be a way to find the fields by name.

Comment: Sure there is: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/.

Comment: This seems like a very strange naming scheme. I don't know how the server code will interpret `POST` fields with names like this.

Comment: I simplified the names down for readability.  The post will iterate over each row and update (C#).  The C# I have down, it is jQuery that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @Barmar, this is what she is trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my commend, iterate over each row and search for all `input`s in each row. If you have to only get the inputs with the specific name, you can use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  // Find the the input we want to set the value of
  $(this).find('input[name*="TotalHours"]').val(
    // Find the inputs we want to sum
    $(this).find('[name*="Sched"], [name*="Comp"], [name*="NoShow"]')
      // Get their values and convert them to numbers
      .map(function() { return Number(this.value); })
      .get()
      // sum the values
      .reduce(function(sum, v) { return sum + v; })
  );
});
```

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  // Find the the input we want to set the value of
  $(this).find('input[name*="TotalHours"]').val(
    // Find the inputs we want to sum
    $(this).find('[name*="Sched"], [name*="Comp"], [name*="NoShow"]')
    // Get theirs values and convert them to numbers
    .map(function() {
      return Number(this.value);
    })
    .get()
    // sum the values
    .reduce(function(sum, v) {
      return sum + v;
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].Sched" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].Comp" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].NoShow" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].TotalHours" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].Sched" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].Comp" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].NoShow" value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].TotalHours" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each row and then inside iterate over each column. If the name doesn't contain `TotalHours` add it's value to the sum. If it does contain `TotalHours` then set the value equal to the sum. Here is an example with values not 0 and not hidden.

```js
$('tr').each(function(index) {
  var sum=0;
  $('td input',this).each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('TotalHours')==-1){
      sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
    }else{
      $(this).val(sum);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].Sched" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].Comp" value="20" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].NoShow" value="30" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[0].TotalHours" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].Sched" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].Comp" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].NoShow" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="[1].TotalHours" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript String [search()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) Method to match the input name.

> Searches a string for a specified value, and returns the position of the match. The value can be string or a regular expression. If no match is found the method returns -1.

Below, an iteration occurs through each `tr`
then each `input`, which searches for
a specific name, if not equal -1, the variable
`totalHours` receives the value:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var totalHours = 0;

    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("name").search("Sched") != -1 
                || $(this).attr("name").search("Comp") != -1 
                || $(this).attr("name").search("NoShow") != -1) {
            totalHours += Number($(this).val());
        } 
    });

    $(this).find('input[name*="TotalHours"]').val(totalHours);
});
```

Check it out:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aprnxztb/1/)

Comment: This appears to be adding the columns of all row together? I would like it to be each row,,,,