# MVC How to pass a list of objects in Model and Bind In View Cshtml

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I want to get a List of items from Model to view, but i am not  getting Exact Idea of That 
Please Help Me 
I am Adding my all class

Below

```
    public class DivisionDTO
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<GroupDTO> Groups { get; set; }
    }
    public class GroupDTO
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }
 public class Team
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }
        public string pld { get; set; }
        public string W { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public string L { get; set; }
        public string GF { get; set; }
        public string GA { get; set; }
        public string GD { get; set; }
        public string Pts { get; set; }
    }
```

The model itself is a list of items and every items contain List of child items as well.
in DivisionDTO Class list GroupDTO values is there and in GroupDTO  class Team value is there

My controller Code is following

```
 public ActionResult EditGroup()
    {
        CreatingLeague.Models.DivisionDTO division = new CreatingLeague.Models.DivisionDTO();
        division.Id = new Guid();
        division.Name = "Div";
        division.Groups = new List<CreatingLeague.Models.GroupDTO>();

        CreatingLeague.Models.Team team = new Models.Team();
        team.TeamName = "TeamA";
        division.Groups.Add(new CreatingLeague.Models.GroupDTO() { Id = new Guid(), Name = "G1", Teams = new List<Team>() { team } });
        return View(division);
    }
```

I want to make a edit page can any one give me idea of that

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the individual groups in the razor View.

```
@model DivisionDTO

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Groups.Count(); i++) {

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Groups[i].Name) 

    @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Groups[i].Teams.Count(); j++) {
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Groups[i].Teams[j].TeamName) 
    }
}
```

Do not use `foreach`, because the indices `i`, `j` are needed by the MVC modelbinder.

Your POST action can take the `DivisonDto` as model, the child collections will have data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(DivisonDto model) {
    var firstGroupName = model.Groups[0].Name;
    // ...
}
```

See [Model Binding to a List MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4)