# Get checked checkbox MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have searched some articles but none of them fits with my problem. i have this code in my cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MonitoreoIntegrado.Models.Sensores>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Graphics", "Datos_extensometro", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:25px;"><input type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Consultar"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:428px; height:105px; padding:5px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <h4 style="margin-top:0px;">Consultar multiples sensores</h4>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.CheckBox("sensoresCB", false, new { value = @item.idSensor.ToString() }) @item.nombre <a class="moverse" objetivo="@(item.idSensor)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" title="Ir al marcador"></span></a><br />
            }
    </div>
}
```

and this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = RolesSistema.Administrador + "," + RolesSistema.Lectura)]
public ActionResult Graphics()
{
    return View();
}
```

I need help to receive that checkboxes in my controller and check which of them are checked

Comment: i have added the model to my view
`@model IEnumerable<MonitoreoIntegrado.Models.Sensores>`

Comment: which i need to receive in my controller is the `idSensor` of the checked boxes. Just that thing is enought for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use unique id's for your inputs. The easiest way:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBox("sensoresCB["+i.ToString()+"]", false, new { value = Model[i].idSensor.ToString() })
    //your other stuff
}
```

And on controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = RolesSistema.Administrador + "," + RolesSistema.Lectura)]
public ActionResult Graphics(bool[] sensoresCB) //note this
{
    return View();
}
```

So you got the array with your selections. Use index to understand what checkbox it is.

Comment: I tried this but i receive all my checkboxes as false. no matter if i check them or not

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the model of `item` with a `Checked` property or similar.

```
public class GraphicsViewModel {
   public GraphicsItemViewModel[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class GraphicsItemViewModel {
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
   public long IdSensor { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can render the checkbox with a binding to this `Checked` property.

```
@model GraphicsViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm(/* ....*/) {
    // use a for loop so the array is bound correctly
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++) { 
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Checked)
       // post back IdSensor value so we can access it in the controller
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].IdSensor) 
    }
}
```

Your controller should accept a model for the POST data, you can reuse the ViewModel:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Graphics(GraphicsViewModel postData) {
  bool areAllChecked = postData.Items.All(i => i.Checked);
  bool isFirstChecked = postData.Items.First().Checked;
  bool isCertainIdChecked = postData.Items.Single(i => i.IdSensor == 1337).Checked;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: my model in this view is very big. It has a lot of properties and subclases in use. making an extended class would make me write a huge constructor for that class. the current model used is taken directly from the  database model. is there any way to just set property checked as false in the view checkbox i always need the checkboxes clear?

Comment: Well the problem is that you need some property to bind the user selected values back so you can work with them in the controller. You could compose a new ViewModel that consists of the database model and the additional properties (without using inheritance).

Comment: still i can't solve this. my model is `@model IEnumerable<MonitoreoIntegrado.Models.Sensores>`
as you can see it is a IEnumerable. so every `Sensores` object should have it's own `Checked` property. and not a list items for each one and I think my controller should receive something like `IEnumerable<Sensores> sensores` as parameter, however, it's not working. i don't know what am i doing bad. I need more help please.

Comment: Using `IEnumerable<Sensores>` as model and having a `Checked` property for every sensor sounds reasonable. There are some pitfalls when model binding collections, see [Model Binding to a List MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4). Basically, you must make sure the rendered `<input/>`  elements have the correct names (which include an index).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention a helpful point here, that is

> If a checkbox is checked, then the postback values will contain a
>   key-value pair of the form [InputName]=[InputValue]
>
> If a checkbox is not checked, then the posted form contains no
>   reference to the checkbox at all.

So in a controller action method, you can use the name of the checkbox and get the values which is only checked

ex:

```
public ActionResult Graphics(bool[] sensoresCB) 
{
    return View();
}
```

Hope above  information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I don't know why but `bool[] sensoresCB` is giving me a null value, even if i check many checkboxes

Comment: just see the name of checkbox in the viewsource of the browser window. that will give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Based on `@teo van kot` reply I achieved to recover the checkboxes values. This is my working code.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = RolesSistema.Administrador + "," + RolesSistema.Lectura)]
public ActionResult Graphics(int[] sensoresCB)//you can receive a string[] as well
{
    //code and stuff
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MonitoreoIntegrado.Models.Sensores>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Graphics", "Datos_extensometro", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //some code stuff
    @{
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.CheckBox("sensoresCB[" + i.ToString() + "]", false, new { value = item.idSensor.ToString() }) @item.nombre<br />
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```