# How to pass value from View to controller after double click edit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that is holding entries from a database inside the table a user can click on any of the entries and be able to edit them. However, my controller doesn't receive the changes. I have tried to save the values onchange to a hidden input but that didn't return anything, but an empty string.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.LoginSecurityRecords)
                    {
                        <tr id="@item.SecurityKey">
                            <td class="displayrow1">
                                <span class="display-mode" name="NewUserID" onchange="document.getElementById('ChangeID').value = this.value">
                                    @item.UserID
                                </span><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                <input name="ChangeID" id="ChangeID" type="hidden"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" data-id="{{@item.SecurityKey->id}}" name="Save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary save" value="@item.SecurityKey" onclick="AdminEditing();" formaction="@Url.Action("Edit")">Save Changes</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
```

My controller is returning an empty string for this:

```
string userId = Request.Form["ChangeID"];
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you having form tag there?

Comment: Yeah, the entire thing is held within a `@using (Html.BeginForm())' I'll add this to the code above.

Comment: You need to index your ID fields like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4

Comment: @SteveGreene please explain why that would help with this circumstance.

Comment: This code `document.getElementById('ChangeID').value` (which should be #ChangeID). If you generate more than 1 row, you will have more than 1 input with the id of ChangeID. If you have more than 1 input, the ids need to be indexed as in link for binding to work.

Comment: I'm just trying to have only one value is stored to that hidden input, so I removed it from the `foreach` and put it outside of it and it still doesn't return a value.

Comment: try removing html.beginForm and just wrap it inside form tag with method=post then on server side try getting the value from Request.Form